# Cloud vision Web Detection in Android

Tags: android, web, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

Hi i have been implementing an application to detect image from Cloud Vision. I have a sample source code for detecting Data's in the following link,

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-vision/blob/master/android/CloudVision/app/src/main/java/com/google/sample/cloudvision/MainActivity.java

But this one doesn't have an option to detect **Web Entities** from cloud so can anyone help me to let me know the possibilities of cloud detection with Android SDK given in the link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sharika, please make sure to accept an answer if it answers your question. It's what helps other users on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Vision API can detect web resources normally, you just have to use the API instead of that sample (which is only a specific application of the general Vision API).

I assume you want to detect what's in the image? If that's the case, you need the [detect labels](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels) option.

You have to make a [AnnotateImageRequest](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#AnnotateImageRequest) which contains an [Image resource](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#Image) which can either be a byte String or a URL (also works with GCS URLs).